# Redux persist data not saving to local storage with store.dispatch

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-persist

It works fine when calling `bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch)` within a react component. This is my code:

```
const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: AsyncStorage,
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducers);
const store = createStore(persistedReducer, {}, applyMiddleware(thunk));

export const persistor = persistStore(store);
export default store;
```

This is the value for `reducers`, the 2nd argument for `persistedReducer`:

```
const reducers = combineReducers({
  installation: installationReducer,
  account: accountReducer,
});
```

as mentioned, calling `bindActionCreators` works, but I want to persist and modify a state value outside of a component.

Comment: as I understand you want to presist some data, right ?

Comment: @Guku yes, I'm using redux and and redux-persist

Answer (score 0):

I beleive in your `persistConfig` you should have `whiteList` and `blackList`

the `blacklist` is where you presisit your data

for example

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import {authReducer} from './auth/reducer';
import {taskReducer} from './task/reducer';
import {persistTaskReducer} from './persistTasks/reducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  task: taskReducer,
  auth: authReducer,
  persistTasks: persistTaskReducer,
 });

const persistConfig = {
 key: 'Root',
 storage: AsyncStorage,
 whiteList: ['persistTasks'],
 blacklist: ['auth', 'task'],
 };
```

read the [docs](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist)

Comment: Hi, I've already tried that route but to no avail. My previous projects do not have whitelist or blacklist but they all worked fine, it's just that they were wrapped in a functional component. The example above is run on a separate .js file.

Comment: in the docs you should use blacklist to presist your data